# Failed to subscribe a ics calendar on iphone via SSL connection

Tags: ios, ssl, https, icalendar

On iphone, opened Settings -> Passwords & Accounts -> Add Account -> Other -> Add Subscribed Calendar and tried to subscribe a ics calendar via a https url like https://example.com/calendar/ics/?calendarId=JTAKihRsRdhcGveNUKdQdp7dBeenhPoSXTvgqhDezTQ

But got the following error popup - "Cannot Connect Using SSL. Do you want to try setting up the account without SSL?"

Cannot find a way to make the https ics url working in iphone. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Does anyone know that can iOS subscribe calendar url which serves a ics string, not a ics file?